# Is using the isInstance method on a static field shared between threads safe?

Tags: java, reflection, concurrency

I'm working on a program where due to various reasons I only know the name of the class I need at runtime, so I have to use reflection to access it. In one particular place in my program I have to check whether an object is an instance of that class, and as I'm using reflection I can't use `instanceof`.

I am storing the object representing the class in a `final static` field and I am checking if other objects are instances of that class using `MY_CLASS.isInstance(obj)`.

However, now I also need to run this check in concurrent manner, meaning that more threads will have access to the `MY_CLASS` field. Given that I don't understand exactly how the `isInstance` method operates (and I don't think it works the exact same way as `instanceof`), I want to know whether this approach is safe to use.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't use `isInstance` on a static field; you read the value of the static field, and then call `isInstance` on that. The read of the field is "thread safe", but by the time you invoke `isInstance` on that value, some other thread might have changed the value under your feet.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't really understand what you mean. How can the value of the field change if it is marked as `final`?

Comment: It should be. The JavaDoc does not say anything about thread safety which we can assume it is thread safe.

Comment: @dadus33 is the `MY_CLASS` variable static and final too?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, I stated that in my post. Also, it wouldn't make sense not to be. `MY_CLASS` is of type `Class` and I only initialize it with the class name I get at runtime using `Class.forName()`

Comment: Oh, in that case there's no problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you. I'd like to understand though in what case it **wouldn't** be safe to run methods on `final static` fields?

Comment: If the object isn't thread safe: for example, `static final List<String> LIST = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: @AndyTurner that really shed some light over my misunderstandings. So basically when I use methods that might change some values in that field, right? For instance, when using `set()` on an `ArrayList`, just like in your example, some value in the underlying array changes, and threads that might access that same value simultaneously might get the value that was previously there or throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if they also want to `set()` something. Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147875/discussion-between-dadus33-and-andy-turner).